# Which of these is the correct usage "working [with / on / in]"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I am trying to update my profile. Which one of these is the correct sentence that I should use in my profile?

1. I am a developer working **on** Microsoft technologies.
2. I am a developer working **in** Microsoft technologies.
3. I am a developer working **with** Microsoft technologies. (Currently, I have this after I tried the above two.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I am a developer working on Microsoft technologies.

This sounds like you are working for Microsoft on their new technologies. If that's true, then you should state what the technologies are.

> I am a developer working in Microsoft technologies.

This sounds like you are working for a division of Microsoft called "technologies".

> I am a developer working with Microsoft technologies.

This sounds like what you are really after: you develop using Microsoft technologies.

Perhaps a better way to say this would be:

> I develop web applications using Microsoft C# and WCF.

... or whatever the real application area and technologies are.

Comment: Working "in" is used for specific field/langauge/technology. eg. I work in crypto/ in c++/in .Net

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. As I said earlier, I currently have "working with" in my profile with the list of technologies listed below.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: yes, making the "technologies" more specific definitely improves the meaning in that option, too.

Comment: @Siva: You're welcome!  Let's see if others chime in, too.

Comment: I don't know if your *better way to say* is motivated solely by the idea of being more specific, but personally I associate *technologies* more with actual hardware. So unless OP actually means his specialist area is MS Kinect or similar, I much prefer your version(s).

Comment: In accord with PeterK. and @FumbleFingers — it might be clearer to say “I am a developer working with (or in or on) Microsoft *software*” if one is not also developing “with” (=by the use of) or “in” (=in the field of) or “on” (which can simply be omitted if one is developing the technology itself) Microsoft *hardware*.

Comment: @Raven yes, I think being more specific and less vague is better. This is a bit of a blast from the past: my answer was given eleven and a half years ago! 

Comment: @PeterK. — Yet it’s still listed on the side-panel, or I’d never have seen it to comment.